# HTML / CSS: semi transparent header - without content / overlay

Tags: html, css, header, transparent

On my current web projekt scrolling should start after the logo and headlines.
Here is the page: http://neos-srv.dyndns.org/restaurantAppHtdocs/site.php

So I created a header and placed the logo and the headlines in the header. But since the area is semi transparent whenever you scroll the content shines through the header.

**So how can I make a semi transparent header which does not overlap with the content?**

Notes:

- The page scrolls only if the browser window / resolution is too small (undo maximize on the browser-window to test)
- The Header needs to be semi transparent in order to show the background picture. I tried already to use a background image for the header which is a piece of the background - but this look only good with the same monitor. Example: http://neos-srv.dyndns.org/restaurantAppHtdocs/site.php?page=restaurants
- Please to not use the internet explorer - since it does not render the site correctly

Comment: I like the jenga on the fries.

Answer (score 0):

Take position fixed off #header and style as display:block or similar. Position:fixed will make the content scroll with the page which is why the image is appearing to go underneath this header section.

Comment: Ahm. I though that fixed makes the div stay at the same position. If I remove fixed the header also scrolls. Can you post a tutorial or a pice of code? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix for FF and Chrome. 
IE and Safari display the page really bad though:

HTML:

```
<div id="header">'
<div id="headerPic" style="background: url(Bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='Bg.jpg', sizingMethod=scale);
-ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='Bg.jpg', sizingMethod=scale);">
<div id="headerContent">
...
</div></div></div>
```

CSS:

```
#header {
    position:fixed;
    display: block;
    top:0px; left:0px; right:0px;
width: 100%px;
    z-index:5;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 215px;
}

#headerPic {
    width: 100%; height: 100%;          
    background: url(images/restaurantsBg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: 100%;
}

#headerContent {
    width: 701px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 215px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.80);
    /* Colors: transparency, r, g, b
    /* For IE 5.5 - 7 */
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#d0ffffff, endColorstr=#d0ffffff);
    /* For IE 8 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#d0ffffff, endColorstr=#d0ffffff)"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.home{
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/nfHr3AD.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position-x: center;
}

.content{
  height: 92vh;
  margin-top: 17vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.header {
  height: 15vh;
  background-color: rgba(71, 83, 143, 0.41);
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="home">
  <div class="header">
    my header content
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h5>first list</h5>
    <h5>first list</h5>
    <h5>first list</h5>
    <h5>first list</h5>
    <h5>first list</h5>
    <h5>first list</h5>
    <h5>first list</h5>
    <h5>first list</h5>
    <h5>first list</h5>
    <h5>first list</h5>
    <h5>first list</h5>
    <h5>first list</h5>
    <h5>first list</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

> This works for me!